# oracle 10g ora-04030 - Is there a query that looks up 'query that causes memory shortage'?

Tags: oracle, memory, oracle10g

After restarting the Oracle service, 'ora-04030' occurs over time.
So, I want to find a query that causes a memory shortage.
Is there such a query?

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer to this error is [add more memory](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1363891100346045112), or [tune your database parameters](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-04030-out-of-process-memory-2/).

But if you think the problem is a SQL query, you can query the dynamic performance views to look for queries which are using large amounts of memory.

```
SELECT substr(sql_text,1,80) sql,
    sharable_mem, executions
FROM V$SQLSTATS
WHERE sharable_mem > 1048576
ORDER BY sharable_mem DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```